# In excel, how can I make a structured reference to another workbook in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I don't want a relative or absolute reference to the other workbook, as it's not 'owned' by me and what I want to know is likely to get shunted around horizontally and vertically. So something like

```
='[the other spreadsheet.xlsx]aWorksheetInSame'!$AW$26
```

is not going to work in this case. If it was a value in the same workbook, I would have something like

```
=othertable[columninothertable]
```

I googled and followed the instructions [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/import-data-from-external-data-sources-power-query-be4330b3-5356-486c-a168-b68e9e616f5a?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fConnect-data-in-another-workbook-to-your-workbook-3a557ddb-70f3-400b-b48c-0c86ce62b4f5http%253a%252f&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US). I managed to set up a link to the other workbook, but how do I actually get certain data to display in the workbook? Do I use a formula?

Also how often will it update? If someone changes a value in the source spreadsheet, will this be reflected in the destination spreadsheet (that's the output I want)

The version is 365 proplus, version is 1902.

Comment: File mentioned in the formula is always searched in some folder. If the name is absolute it is searched in specified location, else if it is not absolute and do not contain drive and/or path part it is searched within workbooks opened in curreent Excel instance, else it is searched like its name is relative to **current drive and folder** which may be NOT equal to the drive/folder where current workbook is stored. Your question makes no sense.

Comment: It makes perfect sense. The file is staying where it is. The information inside it is being moved around.

Comment: You will have to coordinate with the other user as to how/where the cell moves. Perhaps using a named range would solve your problem.